# Unable to get the selected value from dropdownlist when clicked on submit button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Unable to get the selected value from dropdownlist when clicked on submit button.
I created a dropdownlist and a submit button. I created a function for submit button. 
When I clicked on submit button I am unable to get the data for selected values

```
<div class="form-group">

            <select  name ="drop">
              <option value="volvo">dropdown</option>
              <option value="saab">Saab</option>
              <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
              <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          </div>


          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getData()">
            Submit
          </button>



function getData() {
    var user = {
      fname: "",
      lname: "",
      email: "",
      gender: "",
      role : "",
      dropdown : ""
    };

var ddown = document.getElementsByName("drop");
   var sdvalues = [];
   for (i = 0; i < ddown.length; i++) {
    if (ddown[i].selected) {
     sdvalues.push(ddown[i].value);
    }
    user.dropdown = sdvalues;
  }

console.log(user);
  }

I need to get the selected values from dropdownlist, When i clicked on submit button.
```

I created a dropdownlist and a submit button. I created a function for submit button. 
When I clicked on submit button I am unable to get the data for selected values.

Comment: you're grabbing the `drop` element with the selector and then trying to loop over it instead of its children. try `for (let i = 0; i < ddown.childNodes.length; i++)` . also you could just use a singular selector instead of the plural since your only getting the list, unless you want to grab the child nodes right off the bat. then you could you do something like `document.querySelector('[name="drop"]').childNodes`

Comment: Can you make changes for the above code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the array and the object global and call the function on change of the dropdown. Print the data on click of submit button

```js
var user = {
  fname: "",
  lname: "",
  email: "",
  gender: "",
  role: "",
  dropdown: ""
};
var sdvalues = [];

function a() {
  var ddown = document.getElementsByName("drop");
  for (i = 0; i < ddown.length; i++) {
    sdvalues.push(ddown[i].options[ddown[i].selectedIndex].value);
    user.dropdown = sdvalues;
  }
}

function getData() {
  console.log(user);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">

  <select name="drop" onchange="a()">
    <option value="volvo">dropdown</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>


<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getData()" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Its working... But I have and object like this var user = {
  fname: "",
  lname: "",
  email: "",
  gender: "",
  role: "",
  dropdown: ""
};
I need to get the data on click of submit button  for all the elements in one Array...And the function will be getData()... So in that case  what i need to do??
Thanks in Advance

Comment: the object is still present. what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Inside the function I have created the object like this function getData() {
    var user = {
      fname: "",
      lname: "",
      email: "",
      gender: "",
      role : "",
      dropdown : ""
    };
 var rroles = document.getElementsByName("role");
  var rrroles = [];
  for(i=0; i<rroles.length; i++){
   if(rroles[i].checked){ 
    rrroles.push(rroles[i].value);
   }
   user.role = rrroles;

  }

For checkboxes I did like this ...
console.log(user);

Comment: Every time the function is called a new object will be created and the array will be get reset. You have to make it global if you want to store all the select options. Otherwise tje last select option will only go in the array